# Send multidimensional form JSON data via AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck on a multidimensional form issue.

What I'm trying to do is sending via ajax a JSON with a structure like :

```
    {
        "user": 1,
        "quiz": 25,
        "questions": {
            // question 132, hidden input (checkboxes)
            "132": [24536, 566, 64],
            // question 133, hidden input (mixed checkboxes/textarea)
            "133": [2345, "some text from a text area", 456],
            // question 134, hidden input (radio buttons)
            "134": [876]
        },
        "other_data": [2, 543, "test", 989]
    }
```

My Form :

```
<form id="myForm" action="myAPI.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="quiz" value="25">

    <p>Question A</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="132">
    a1
    <input name="answer[]" type="checkbox" value="a"><br>
    a2
    <input name="answer[]" type="checkbox" value="b"><br>
    a3
    <input name="answer[]" type="checkbox" value="c"><br>

    <p>Question B</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="133"  >
    a1
    <input name="answer[]" type="checkbox" value="d"><br>
    a2
    <input name="answer[]" type="checkbox" value="e"><br>
    a3
    <textarea name="answer_" rows="3"></textarea><br>

    <p>Question C</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="134">
    a1
    <input name="answer" type="radio" value="f"><br>
    a2
    <input name="answer" type="radio" value="g"><br>
    a3
    <input name="answer" type="radio" value="h"><br>

    <hr> 
    <button type="submit">invia</button>

</form>
```

My Ajax

```
var myForm    = $('form#myForm'),
    response  = $('#myForm-response');

myForm.submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var url  = myForm.attr('action'),
        data = JSON.stringify(myForm.serializeArray());

    // JSON example I'd like to send
    /*var data = {
        "user": 1,
        "quiz": 25,
        "questions": {
            "132": ['24536, 566, 64'],
            "133": [2345, "some text from a text area", 456],
            "134": [876]
        }
    }*/

    $('#console-output').html('data : ' + data);
    console.log('data : ' + data);

    $.ajax(
    {
        method     : "POST",
        url        : url,
        data       : data,
        processData: false,
        dataType   : 'html',
        beforeSend : function()
        {
            //console.log('beforeSending: ' + data);
        },
        success    : function(result)
        {
            //console.log('success!' + result);
            response.html(result);
        },
        error      : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            //console.log(xhr);
            if(typeof console != "undefined")
                console.log(xhr + " - " + ajaxOptions + " - " + thrownError);

            response.html(xhr + " - " + ajaxOptions + " - " + thrownError);
        },
        complete   : function()
        {
            //console.log('complete:');
        }
    });
})
```

And the output is :

```
[{
    "name": "user",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "name": "quiz",
    "value": "25"
}, {
    "name": "question",
    "value": "132"
}, {
    "name": "answer[]",
    "value": "b"
}, {
    "name": "answer[]",
    "value": "c"
}, {
    "name": "question",
    "value": "133"
}, {
    "name": "answer[]",
    "value": "e"
}, {
    "name": "answer_",
    "value": "test"
}, {
    "name": "question",
    "value": "134"
}, {
    "name": "answer",
    "value": "g"
}]
```

Any tip? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's correct behaviour for `serializeArray()`. To build the structure you require you'd need to write you own logic.

Comment: Your form is not structured like the JSON object you want to create. Also, I wouldn't call `myForm.serializeArray()`. That would be why what it does generate is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using [formToObject.js](https://github.com/serbanghita/formToObject.js) :)